# Google One-tap declares global variable L

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster, google-identity

The Google One-tap library causes errors when used with other libraries because it declares a global variable L.

I see this in the minified code but I am not sure what it is doing.

```
var L = 0;
function K(g) {
  return "jscomp_symbol_" + (g || "") + L++
}
```

That conflicts with other libraries like LeafletJS that also define a global L
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet

I can't find an open source project for Google's One-tap code to submit a patch. How do I work around this?

Comment: This is a bug in Google's release process; it should be wrapped in an IIFE.

Comment: That code comes from https://github.com/openid/OpenYOLO-Web

Comment: We are currently fixing the bug.

Comment: We are working on fixing this, I will update when it's ready. Sorry about that, but thanks for reporting, feel free to contact sso@google.com if you need more info or have other feedback.

Comment: This has been fixed, the L variable is no more declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the product manager at Google for this library. This should be fixed now. Sorry about that and thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 2):

Until the bug is corrected in Google One-tap file, you can simply use Leaflet's [`noConflict`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#noconflict) mode so that you can reassign Leaflet to any other global variable name you like, and avoid those used by Google library. Since the latter is a minified file, most variables and functions will be 1 or 2 characters long.

```js
// Should actually be BELOW the HTML part,
// but SO insists on displaying the JS part first.

var map = Leaflet.map("map").setView([48.86, 2.35], 12);

Leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<script>
  // Re-assign L from Leaflet to any other global variable, and avoid conflict
  // with other libraries, like Google One-tap in this case.
  var Leaflet = L.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="https://smartlock.google.com/client"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ghybs! Unfortunately for us we are using multiple Leaflet libraries, including [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster). That library is looking for window.L so I don't know if saving off the Leaflet library will work for us. Any suggestions?